# Troubleshooting a MATLAB created function

Tags: matlab

Good day!

I am fairly new to MATLAB and I seem to be having some problems with making a simple function. The function is suppose to output a concatenated 4*4 matrix. My code is as follows:

```
function T_G = JointMatrix(alpha,a,theta,d)
% The general transformation matrix for joint n from joint n-1.
% Prompt: Input row parameter values to recieve matrix.
T_G = zeros(4,4);
R = [cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0;
    sind(theta)*cosd(alpha) cosd(theta)*cosd(alpha) -sind(alpha);
    sind(theta)*sind(alpha) cosd(theta)*sind(alpha) cosd(alpha);0 0 0];
P = [a;-sind(alpha)*d;cosd(alpha)*d;1];
T_G = [R P]
end
```

Comment: The error that I receive is that MATLAB says that my function is an  "Undefined function or variable 'JointMatrix'."

Comment: "I seem to be having some problems" doesn't tell us anything about what the problems are. You don't go to the doctor and say "I seem to be having some symptoms", do you?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.

```
JointMatrix(0,1,0,1)

T_G =

     1     0     0     1
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     1
     0     0     0     1
```

Make sure you are in the right directory.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I made a syntax error or something. Rookie mistake on my part.